# main.Critical: Invalid Method

Tags: magento2, php

I keep getting this error:

> main.CRITICAL: Invalid method
>   Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login::_getColSet [] []

method:

```
protected function _getColSet()
{
    return 'col'.$this->numEnabled.'-set';
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because you're calling that method from outside of `Inchoo\SocialConnect\Block\Login` and as it's a protected method you're not allowed to do that.

Comment: ah, i'll change the method to public and see if it works

Comment: This fixed the error, but i'm getting another error which is puzzling me, are you able to help me?

Comment: @Callum please post a new question ;)